Common sense of what means a device that requires +5V/-5V? (negative voltage without ground)
this question maybe is more about common sense in sheets, I take the assumption you know what a negative voltage is.
I was looking this:
https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/c13852-1350ga_etc_kacc1274e.pdf
A funny device to measure light, everything seems nice until you read the power description which is aprox:
-Vs: -5V
+Vs: 5V
no ground
I really don't have idea what they are requesting!, if a sheet request you a negative and positive voltage without ground, what means?
Lets remember Voltage works as a differential of two cables, so request -5V/+5V would be the same as request 0V/10V, the connection does not show any ground to supply a right negative voltage, maybe sheets with this just implies a 0V/10V?
Even if we have a power source that has ground, and is able to create an offset on the voltage to generate a -5V/+5V from the ground of it, from the device perspective it should be a 0V/10V, or ok, would be any value with a differential of 10V.
Why some sheets show voltages like that? I would understand if they use ground, but maybe even with them it has a different meaning.
Which is the right way to interpret this?
The power connector on the PDF is: Power connector 53048-0610 (Molex)
Thx!

Are you sure it doesn't have a ground? I can't seem to find any information on the pinout of that connector on it.

that is a good question, from the info they have the answer is no, I has been waiting time to get also this answer, maybe there is even use for other pins. Someone who has used it said to me only used +Vs and -Vs nothing more to use it, he did not tell me the specific configuration he used for it.

Searching the PDF gives no hits for the phrase "no ground". Where did you find this statement in the linked PDF?

"the connection does not show any ground." Please add an image of the connector or at least a link to it!

They only request +Vs and -Vs, and other ppl who also used it only used that two, no ground.

Given they use a 14-pin connector for power, it would be very surprising if there is no ground connection. The other people might just not be mentioning the ground connection, which would be very normal when talking about the power requirements for a module like this.

so, is more likely the sheet is incomplete, which is unusual? or is usual to them lack of this type of information?

No, it's not unusual. If I say "this device needs a +5 V power supply", it's understood there will also be a ground connection to the power supply---it would be very unusual to mention the ground connection separately. The instructions here say "To use the MPPC module, connect it to an external power supply by using the power cable that came supplied with the MPPC module"(p. 2). Dollars to donuts when you get the cable it will have three contacts on the power supply end.

@Abs_0_ you can't have a +5 V and -5 V without a reference to measure from, otherwise the required voltage would be 10 V

The "Electrical and optical characteristics" table in the datasheet specifies different currents for the +5 and -5 V supplies, which wouldn't be possible without a 0 V connection.

Well, voltage is relative as described on the post, actually the -5V/5V is the same to 0V/10V, the common sense can be pretty important here, this question is not a tech one, I already said that from the start :)

If I say "this device needs a +5 V power supply", it's understood there will also be a ground connection to the power supply --- it would be very unusual to mention the ground connection separately. The instructions here say "To use the MPPC module, connect it to an external power supply by using the power cable that came supplied with the MPPC module" (p. 2).
Dollars to donuts when you get the cable it will have three contacts on the power supply end, for +5, -5, and ground.
If by some chance it doesn't, then you have your answer and this device doesn't actually need a ground connection to the power supply.

This solve the question which was focused in the common sense, aside I have the cable, which comes with 6 cables, 1 red, 2 black, 1 gray, 1 white, 1 yellow.

Hopefully it came with some instructions indicating which color goes to which voltage.

When the supply requirements are stated as ±5V, it's implied that the circuitry requires a low impedance source of 0V, half-way between +5V and -5V, shown left here:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
We can infer that internally the appliance would require access to that zero-volt source, a physical connection to it, and that the equipment will require a supply with three terminals, F, H and G.
If a power supply doesn't have such a terminal of "mid-point" potential, then the circuitry using it would not "know" the difference between a single-ended 10V supply (above middle), or any other configuration of sources that produce a potential difference of 10V (above right). In such a case, I would expect an appliance to state its supply requirements as just "10V", which implies a single-ended two-terminal supply.
Sometimes manufacturers state a dual-supply requirement in the form "+5V/0V/−5V", a nice way to avoid the ambiguity that caused you this confusion.

thx for the answer! would be nice if the manufacture would have provided that way to declare it, how is a incomplete sheet, this only can be confirmed once they answer me.
